# OpenGL drawing textured quad as a solid colour

Tags: opengl

I would like to generate a texture every update loop and display it on a quad. I've looked at numerous tutorials and can only find segments of code instead of complete examples.

First I define the texture and create the data.

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

auto *data = new unsigned char[CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * 4];

// Element* elements[4096];

for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * 4; i += 4) {
    Element *element = elements[i / 4];
    if (element != nullptr) {
        data[i] = element->r * 255;
        data[i + 1] = element->g * 255;
        data[i + 2] = element->b * 255;
        data[i + 3] = element->a * 255;
    } else {
        data[i] = 0;
        data[i + 1] = 0;
        data[i + 2] = 0;
        data[i + 3] = 0;
    }
}
```

Then I draw it.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.5f + chunkX * CHUNK_SIZE, 0.5f + chunkY * CHUNK_SIZE, 0);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
glVertex2d(0, 0);
glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
glVertex2d(CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
glVertex2d(CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE);
glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
glVertex2d(0, CHUNK_SIZE);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

The quad is rendering in the correct positions but it is solid red.

[image]

What is the correct way of generating a texture at runtime and drawing it?

Comment: When exactly would `element` be `nullptr`? You assigned it to the address of an array element. Even if the array itself were `nullptr`, the address of any element other than the first will not be zero.

Comment: `elements` is a 1d array containing Element pointers that can be nullptr. It represents a chunk containing 64x64 elements. If the element is null then I want to draw a black pixel in the texture. If the element is found I want to get the colour from the element. I've updated the question to specify its type.

Comment: try to set `glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);` before your `glBegin(...);`  if it makes any difference... If you have enabled lighting you should also set `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);` what is in your `data[]` after generation? try to inspect it or save to file and open with hex editor ... what is in your `elements[4096]` ? how big is `CHUNK_SIZE` hope its `< sqrt(4096)` ...

Answer (score 0):

The texture wasn't displaying as I was enabling `GL_TEXTURE` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

This made the textures render however they were faded and seemingly affecting other textures. After adding `glColor3f(1,1,1);` before rendering the quads it fixed this.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.5f + chunkX * CHUNK_SIZE, 0.5f + chunkY * CHUNK_SIZE, 0);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, whiteTextureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glColor3f(1,1,1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
glVertex2d(0, 0);
glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
glVertex2d(CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
glVertex2d(CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE);
glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
glVertex2d(0, CHUNK_SIZE);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```